# How do I target any CSS property using multiple radio buttons? To assign diff- values to the CSS property when different Radio btn are checked

Tags: html, css

I want to assign different values to a CSS property for some other element when different radio buttons are checked.

```
`<input type="radio" name="for-image" id="img-1">
 <input type="radio" name="for-image" id="img-2">
 <input type="radio" name="for-image" id="img-3">`
```

Comment: the question is not that clear. Maybe try to refer MRE first ?

Comment: Please could you describe what CSS property you want to change - are you sure it will actually affect the look of a radio button or is it some other element you want to style?

Comment: I want to change the CSS property of some other element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS selectors for that. With CSS selectors you can target elements like so: `div:first-of-type` or `div:nth-of-type(3)`.

You may also need to use the `:checked` selector to trigger styles for when a checkbox is selected. CSS selectors can be combined too!

To see how they work and which CSS selectors are there for you to use, please read this link: [W3Schools CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)